# Trying to access QGLWidget from entire application

Tags: c++, opengl, qt4, qglwidget

What I am basically trying to do is to create one instance of a `QGLWidget` (or rather a derived class of `QGLWidget`), add it to a `QMainWindow`, and then access the `QGLWidget`'s rendering context from anywhere in my QTCreator program to be able to call naked OpenGL anywhere I chose to.

Things I have tried:

1) Creating a subclass of `QGLWidget` called `OGLWidget` and making that into a singleton, and then trying to subclass the singleton class "OGLWidget". I thought this would give me access to the same rendering context that the OGLWidget singleton was using but it didn't work.

2) using the constructor `QGLWidget(QWidget * parent, QGLWidget * shared, Qt::WindowFlags)`. For this one I tried casting the singleton object to a QGLWidget and then sticking it in this constructor when I was subclassing QGLWidget in another class called "Display". I tried calling makeCurrent before each classes openGl calls but only the original singleton would draw. I also checked isSharing and that returned true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, although signals\slots are a powerful and awesome feature of Qt I would never use them in my rendering routines because of the added overhead and render order problems; especially the latter. Besides, it's not necessary to do it the way you propose.
Thus, your idea of scattering the rendering routines all over your project is a very bad idea in my opinion. 
What I do in my own project is the following:

My derived `QGLWidget` owns a `Renderer` class that's implemented as a Singleton. It contains all of the OpenGl calls in a few functions. I've created a system where everything that's drawable derives from the same base class. When I want to render, I build a render queue which I implemented as a `priority_queue` with custom sort function. When It's time for rendering a frame I just keep poppin' and rendering until the queue is empty.
Doing this with an event driven render system, while maintaining correct render order would probably drive you insane.

For completeness, my (simplified) QGLWidget definition:

```
#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>

#include "global.h"
#include "renderer.h"

/**
 * Derivation of QGLWidget.
 */
class Engine : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Renderer* renderer;
private slots:
    void renderTimeout(); // my render-loop is timer based
    void onTap(QMouseEvent* qme);
    void onMove(QMouseEvent* qme);
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    /* for debugging I use QPainter for drawing overlays, 
     * so I can't use PaintGL */
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event); 
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* qme);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* qme);
public:
    Engine( QWidget* parent = 0 );
    ~Engine();
signals:
    void tapOccurred(QMouseEvent* qme);
    void moveOccurred(QMouseEvent* qme);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use what Qt has been designed for: use signals and slots? Maybe your problem is more complicated than what I get from it at first glance, but it seems to me that if you add slots to your `QGLWidget` and connect them to signals anywhere in your application, you accomplish exactly what you want. Connecting them can for example be done in the `QMainWindow`. This slot can then make a call to an implementation of `paintGL()` or `paintEvent()` to update the area in `QGLWidget`. Like this:

```
class MyQGLWidget : public QGLWidget {
// constructors and destructor...

protected:
    void paintGL();      // <-- implement this in any way you want if you use OpenGL
    void paintEvent();   // <-- or implement this one if you prefer using QPainter

public slots:
    void updateMyWindow();
}

void MyQGLWidget::updateMyWindow() {
    // Change some data here in any way you like
    // ...

    paintGL();
}
```

Comment: in my opinion this will result in horrible spaghetti code with very hard to debug OpenGl rendering bugs. I agree that signals\slots are almost mandatory when using Qt but I only use it when the receiving object is not dependent of global state (i.e. OpenGl in this case).

Comment: Right, I see what you mean, but I don't quite agree. I think it may depend on how complicated your programme is, but this approach has always worked perfectly in my (relatively small) applications. And incidentally, it's pretty similar to the approach of most Qt example projects.

Comment: For small applications it will work fine yes, this is also my experience. At the moment I'm working on an Android game and I felt reborn after moving all the OpenGl code to a single class. I must note that I need strict rendering order, furthermore there are many objects with different rendering parameters and I needed a way to easily minimize state changes. So I settled on the method described in my answer. But this is mostly taste\opinion yes, there was no performance issue that made me take this route.